# Binomial GLM in R: what do the coefficients talk about?

Tags: r, glm

I'd like to uderstand what the coefficents of the binomial GLM models are. In my hypothetical data:

```
# Create the dataset
set.seed(1)
n <- 50
cov <- 10
x <- c(rep(0,n/2), rep(1, n/2))
p <- 0.4 + 0.2*x
y <- rbinom(n, cov, p)
```

Now we fit a logistic regression model with x as a covariate, using the logit link:

```
model0 <- glm(cbind(y, cov-y) ~ x, family="binomial")
summary(model0)
# Call:
# glm(formula = cbind(y, cov - y) ~ x, family = "binomial")

# Deviance Residuals: 
#      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
# -1.50013  -0.58688  -0.05123   0.48348   2.43452  

# Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
# (Intercept)  -0.3064     0.1280  -2.394 0.016668 *  
# x             0.6786     0.1815   3.739 0.000185 ***
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

# (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

#     Null deviance: 53.720  on 49  degrees of freedom
# Residual deviance: 39.537  on 48  degrees of freedom
# AIC: 177.99

# Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

Returning to the original data scale

```
model_intercept <- 1/(1+(1/(exp(model0[[1]][1]))))
model_intercept
# (Intercept) 
#       0.424
model_x <- 1/(1+(1/(exp(model0[[1]][2]))))
model_x
#         x 
# 0.6634292
```

And here from me starting a big confusion. The 0.6634292 values mean that the y increases at a rate of 0.6634292 per unit of x. Or 0.6634292 means 66,34292% mean increase rate of y with x interval used. And
about the intercept? Something like despite x the y starts at 0.4 units, despite the negative value in the binomial model.

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: The coefficients in a binomial glm represent log odds. The model is saying that at x = 0, the log odds of a positive outcome is -0.3064. This means the _odds_ of a positive outcome is `exp(-0.3064)` or 0.736. As a probability, this is 0.736 / (1 + 0.736), or about 0.42. This is very close to the probability you specified of 0.4 at x = 0.

Comment: Meanwhile, at x = 1, the odds are exp(-0.3064 + 0.6786) = 1.451, so the probability of a positive outcome is 1.451/(1 + 1.451) or 0.592. This is again close to the specified probability of 0.6 at x = 1.

Comment: Note that in this case you have a binary independent variable and binary dependent variable, so you could just do a Fisher test or Chi Squared test instead.